# Parse JavaScript returned [object, Object] when retrieving information from parse object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, parse-platform

It seems when I am trying to retrieve information from my parse data I am having no issue displaying the information from the user table onto my document but when I try to query another object & insert it into an id element with jQuery using either `text();`, `html();`, or `val();` I either get nothing or the text becomes into `[object Object]`. Below is the code I have written down. I also tried a JavaScript method & same output I get `[object Object]`. Also when I console log JSON `stringify query.get("fieldone")` I get this.

> {"_resolved":false,"_rejected":false,"_resolvedCallbacks":[],"_rejectedCallbacks‌​":[]}

How can I convert it into the string value I want to retrieve. Below is the code

```
     var currentUser = Parse.User.current();



     if (currentUser) {
         var UserInfo = Parse.Object.extend("UserInfo");
         var query = new Parse.Query(UserInfo);
         query.equalTo("user", currentUser);
         query.find({
            success: function(UserInfo) {
           // The object was retrieved successfully.


           console.log(JSON.stringify(query.get("fieldone")));

           document.getElementById('fieldone').innerHTML = query.get("fieldone");

            $('#fieldtwo').html(query.get("fieldtwo"));

            $('#startDate').html(query.get("startdate"));

            $('#endDate').html(query.get("enddate"));
        },
        error: function(object, error) {
          // The object was not retrieved successfully.
          // show alert
      }

    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your success function is wrong. [`query.get`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_get) does a query, just like `query.find`, it returns a promise (your `console.log` shows it) and should have a `success` function too (each of them).

Anyway, the success function receive the object or array of objects you're trying to find/query, try this:

```
success: function(userFound) {
    // The user was retrieved successfully.
    console.log(userFound);
}
```

You should see your user with all his properties.

Answer (score 0):

When you call query.find, you will receive ALL users (in an ARRAY) that match the conditions you set. In this case, it would be just one user.

In this simple example, you could use GET or FIRST, that makes more sense. And you should also use promises (done/fail) instead of callback blocks, because they can be chained and you have improved readability.

And, the final answer, to get the value of a field, you should use GET in the OBJECT, not in the query.

So, my suggestion for your code would be:

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
if (currentUser) {
    var UserInfo = Parse.Object.extend("UserInfo");
    var query = new Parse.Query(UserInfo);
    query.get(currentUser.id).done(function(userQueried) {
        // The object was retrieved successfully.
        console.log(JSON.stringify(userQueried));
        document.getElementById('fieldone').innerHTML = userQueried.get("fieldone");
        $('#fieldtwo').html(userQueried.get("fieldtwo"));
        $('#startDate').html(userQueried.get("startdate"));
        $('#endDate').html(userQueried.get("enddate"));
    }).fail(function(error) {
        // The object was not retrieved successfully.
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

That's it!